# Get email address from href link

Tags: php, string

How would I extract only the email address from any given `href`?

```
$str = 'mailto:john.doe@outlook.co.uk?subject=hiya';
```

Currently I do it like this:

```
$str = str_replace('mailto:', '', $str);
$str = explode('?', $str);
$str = $str[0];
```

But is this the best way and could it ever get caught out?

Comment: Looks OK to me, what do you mean with "get caught out" ?

Answer (score 1):

alternativelly, you might use `parse_url`:

```
<?php

$str = 'mailto:john.doe@outlook.co.uk?subject=hiya';
print_r(parse_url($str));

?>

Array
(
    [scheme] => mailto
    [path] => john.doe@outlook.co.uk
    [query] => subject=hiya
)
```

Comment: This feels like a much cleaner approach

Answer (score 0):

Personally i would make this a reusable function and do something similar to below.

```
function extract_emails($str){
    // This regular expression extracts all emails from a string:
    $regexp = '/([a-z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-z0-9]{2,4})+/i';
    preg_match_all($regexp, $str, $m);

    return isset($m[0]) ? $m[0] : array();
}
```

Examples

> 'mailto:john.doe@outlook.co.uk?subject=hiya'
>
> returns ['john.doe@outlook.co.uk']
>
> 'mailto:john.doe@outlook.co.uk?subject=hiya
>   my name is josh this is a test test@hotmail.co.uk'
>
> returns ['john.doe@outlook.co.uk', 'test@hotmail.co.uk']

This will extract emails from anywhere in the text supplied and can handle multiple email extracts. So now you can pass in a full sentence and it will return you a array of emails. This way you got something which in theory is completey reusable if the scope every increases.